# How large of a file can I open on my Mac?

Tags: mac, video, memory

Not technically a programming question. I want to do video editing with my Mac. I have 2GB of RAM. My helmet camera can store up to 16GB of footage.

Can I open a 16GB file and edit it with just 2GB of RAM or should I stop and restart my helmet camera in order to have several smaller files that I can work with?

Answer (score 1):

Several smaller files would be nice, but remember it's not loading the entire file into RAM. Most video editing programs maintain a [scratch disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_space) that is used to store temporary information and process the file.

In short you do not need to stop and restart simply because the file is bigger then the amount of RAM you have.